# Python Regexp problem

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm trying to regexp a line from a webpage. The line is as follows:

```
<tr><td width=60 bgcolor='#ffffcc'><b>random Value</b></td><td align=center width=80>
```

This is what I tried, but it doesn't seem to work, can anyone help me out? 'htmlbody' contains the html page and no, I did not forget to import 're'.

```
reg = re.compile("<tr><td width=60 bgcolor='#ffffcc'><b>([^<]*)</b></td><td align=center width=80>")
value = reg.search(htmlbody)
print 'Value is', value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may want  to use `findall` rather than `search`:

```
reg = re.compile("<tr><td width=60 bgcolor='#ffffcc'><b>([^<]*)</b></td><td align=center width=80>")
value = reg.findall(htmlbody)
print 'Found %i match(es)' % len(value)
```

I have to caution you, though, that regular expressions are notoriously poor at handling HTML.  You're better off using a proper parser using the [HTMLParser module built in to Python](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html).

Answer (score 4):

There is no surefire way to do this with a regex.  See [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why.  What you need is an HTML parser like [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class FindTDs(HTMLParser):
        def __init__(self):
                HTMLParser.__init__(self)
                self.level = 0

        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
                if tag == 'td':
                        self.level = self.level + 1

        def handle_endtag(self, tag):
                if tag == 'td':
                        self.level = self.level - 1

        def handle_data(self, data):
                if self.level > 0:
                        print data

find = FindTDs()

html = "<table>\n"
for i in range(3):
        html += "\t<tr>"
        for j in range(5):
                html += "<td>%s.%s</td>" % (i, j)
        html += "</tr>\n"
html += "</table>"

find.feed(html)
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
import re

htmlbody = "<tr><td width=60 bgcolor='#ffffcc'><b>random Value</b></td><td align=center width=80>"

reg = re.compile("<tr><td width=60 bgcolor='#ffffcc'><b>([^<]*)</b></td><td align=center width=80>")
value = reg.search(htmlbody).group(1)
print 'Value is', value
```

prints out

```
Value is random Value
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Not completely. It works when the <tr>... string is appointed to htmlbody. However in my script htmlbody is a whole HTML-page. And in that case it doesn't seem to work. I forgot to tell: the page contains multiple instances of this line...

Comment: Do you mean that <tr> may be on previous line? Is it possible to exclude it from regexp? You can try reading all the lines, glue them together without linebreaks and search for all occurrences of specific regexp. Or you can try to make regexp more general.